# trying to look for a workaround for the deprecated g:submittoremote button in gsp

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, gsp

While trying to look for an alternative to the g:submittoremote button for ajax calls, I have the following which is not working. Can someone please help. Thank you
This is basically a small grails gsp template with some info and 3 buttons(one submit, one link and one just plain button for an ajax call). The javascript code is embedded in it.
Thank you erichelgeson.
I am enclosing a complete application with information at the top of the code.

```
// here is the complete example.
// using groovy 3.0.4; grails 4.0.3;
// jquery-ui 1.12 and the corresponding jquery.js
// It has ajax calls originating from the top level gsp associted with
// the buttons i_bGreet, i_bTmplGreet;
// additionally there are 2 more calls from the template gsp file associated
// with the buttons i_greetForm_morningBtn, i_greetForm_eveningButton.
// As you can see the call from the main gsp (top level) is working, while with similar code
// from the template page is not working.
//
// top level gsp page: test.gsp
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <g:javascript library="jquery"/>
    <g:javascript library="jquery-ui"/>
    <title>Test Application</title>

    <g:external dir='stylesheets' file='jquery-ui.css'/>
    <g:external dir='stylesheets' file='jquery-ui.theme.min.css'/>
    <g:external dir='stylesheets' file='test.css'/>

    <g:external dir='javascripts' file='jquery.js'/>
    <g:external dir='javascripts' file='jquery-ui.js'/>

    <g:external dir='javascripts' file='test.js'/>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="i_all">
        <div id="i_left">
            <div>
                <button class="button" id="i_bGreet">TopLevelGreet</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class="button" id="i_bTmplGreet">TemplateGreet</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="i_right">
            <div id="i_top"></div>
            <div id="i_bottom"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
//
//
// controller testController.groovy
package example

class TestController {

    def index() { redirect(action: "test")}

    def test() {
        // everything is in test.gsp page
    }
    def tmplgreet(){
        if (params.containsKey('name')) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            params.name = "John Doe"
        }
        render template: 'greet', model: [name: params.name]
    }

    def greet(){
        render "Good Morning/Evening ??"
    }

    def greetMorning(){
        def msg = "Good Morning "
        if (params.containsKey('name')) {
            msg += params.name
        } else {
            msg += "John Doe"
        }
        render msg
    }
    def greetEvening(){
        def msg = "Good Evening "
        if (params.containsKey('name')) {
            msg += params.name
        } else {
            msg += "John Doe"
        }
        render mag
    }
}
//
//
// template view _greet.gsp
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>

<g:form name="i_greetForm">
    <label for="i_name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="i_name" value="John Doe">
    <fieldset class="buttons">
        <td><button class="button" id="i_greetForm_morningBtn">Morning</button>
        <td><button class="button" id="i_greetForm_eveningBtn">Evening</button>
    </fieldset>
</g:form>
//
//
// javascript file test.js
$(document).ready (function() {

    $("#i_bTmplGreet").click(function (e) {
        alert("Selected Template Level Greet");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/test/tmplgreet',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#i_bottom').html(data);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("Failed on TmplLevelGreet. Msg: " + msg);
            }
        });
    });

    $("#i_bGreet").click(function (e) {
        alert("Selected Top Level Greet");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/test/greet',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#i_top').html(data);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("Failed on TopLevelGreet. Msg: " + msg);
            }
        });
    });
    $("#i_greetForm_morningBtn").click(function (e) {
        alert( "Selected MorningBtn");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/test/greetMorning',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#i_bottom').html(data);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("Failed on Greet. Msg: " + msg);
            }
        });
    });
    $("#i_greetForm_eveningBtn").click(function (e) {
        alert("Selected EveningBtn");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/test/greet',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#i_bottom').html(data);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("Failed on Greet. Msg: " + msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
//
//
// css file test.css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    width: 100%;
}
#i_all {
    width: 100%;
}
#i_left {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    margin: 5px;
    padding-top: 1em;
    border-color: #444;
    /*background-color: #777;*/
}
#i_right {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 1em;
    border-color: #444;
    /*background-color: #777;*/
}

#i_top {
    float: top;
    /*background-color: #666;*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    height: 70%;
    width: 98%;
}

#i_bottom {
    /*clear: both;*/
    float: bottom;
    backgroud-color: green;
    height: 30%;
    width: 98%;
}

.button {
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px;
}
```

Comment: What isn't working about it?

Comment: there are 2 cases 1) a button, and an action submit. Button javascript is not being called. In the second case, it is calling the action but it is not updating only a portion of the screen with the result, rather the entire page.  Basically, all I am looking for is an example of making an ajax call upon pressing a button from a groovy TEMPLATE page and update a portion of the main page with the result. Thank you.

Comment: Previously, I used to get that thing done by the g:subtoremote tag, which is being deprecated. I am looking for an alternative way to do that in grails 4/groovy 3. I am using the jqueryui.12.1.4

Comment: There's not enough here to reproduce. If you could upload a sample app that would help. My best guess is that jquery being loaded after your script - so it's not working as the page doesnt know about jquery yet when your code is evaluated. Please look at deferred scripts or extract the script to a file loaded after.

Comment: Thank you erichelgeson. I have included a complete small example.